# WebView in VerticalStackLayout does not size correctly - dotnet Maui

Tags: xaml, layout, webview, maui

In my application I want to have a WebView in a verticalStackLayout, surrounded by a scrollview. The user should not scroll inside the Webview, but scroll down the scrollviewer which also encompasses the label. The label should therefore only be visible when the user has scrolled to the end of the WebView (The WebView will take up more space than the page). I hope this visualisation will help understand my request:

[image]

This however does not seem to work, because the WebView, always only takes up minimal space when in a VerticalStackLayout. I also didn't get it to work with any of the VerticalOptions, is there any way to achieve the result I want?

What happens in my case:

[image]

XAML:

```
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <WebView Source="test.html" Background="red"/>
            <Label 
            Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

test.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<div>
<p style='margin-left:20pt;'>
   <span style='font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";font-size: 40px'>TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT,  TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please post the code of the `test.html`?

Comment: I Added the html markup and improved the Question, I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height of the content of the `test.html` should not be enough.

For a test, you can try to set a fixed height for your `WebView`.

For example:

```
<ScrollView>
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <WebView Source="test.html" Background="red" HeightRequest="1000"/>
        <Label 
        Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And if you want the `WebView` to occupy the remaining height in addition to the Label height, you can use `Grid` to achieve this. We just need to set the  `<RowDefinition Height="*" />` for the first row.

Please refer to the following code:

```
<ScrollView>
    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="90" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <WebView Source="test.html" Background="red" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Label   Grid.Row="1"
        Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </Grid>
</ScrollView>
```

### **Update:**

Based on your code, I did a test on my side,but I couldn't reproduce this problem.

The steps are as follows:

create a file `test.html` and put it into folder `MyMauiApp/Resources/Raw`. And set the `Build Action` to `MauiAsset`.

The code of `test.html` is :

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
      <div>
            <p style='margin-left:20pt;'>
                  <span style='font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";font-size: 40px'>
                        TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT,  TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT, TESTTEXT
                  </span>
            </p>
      </div>
```

And the xaml code is:

```
<ScrollView>
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <WebView Source="test.html" Background="red"/>
        <Label 
        Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Note:

I tested on android emulator (Pixel 5- API 33(Android 13.0)).

Comment: Thanks for your effort! 
My test was on an IPhone 14 Plus simulator (iOS 16.4), I'm sorry for not specifying that. I also tested it on anroid, and just as you, I got the desired result. The problem seems to only accur on iOS. 
Is this a bug in Maui or can something be done about that?

Comment: Yes, this is a known issue.  You can follow it up  [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10777). But as a workaround, you can try to replace the outer StackLayout with a Grid.